# Cookie pop-up on a landing page redirected from email -> Cloud page

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, cookies

We are trying to setup a pop-up for cookie consent (1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th) on landing page published in Cloud Page on which customers are redirected from a sent email?

Comment: Please provide some evidence of your research so far. SFSE is not a service where solutions are provided to custom requirements. There are numerous examples, specifically on Stackoverflow, of how you build cookie pop-ups.